# Nested loop to Iterate Values from/of 2 combo boxes

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am making a College Admission Management System; there are 2 tables named Categories and Groups.

The category contains a field named Category which contains values like 'Army Serving' , `Army Retired, Civilian` , etc.. while Groups Table has a field named Group that contains values such as `Pre-Engineering, Pre-Medical` etc..

I am successfully able to preview all lists separately by selecting the category and group from combo boxes in a form, and I am also able to create a Merit list of students that have the required marks to get admitted.

Now, I want to automate it, like a `'Generate All'` and `'Create All'` Button that would generate all Merit Lists according to their category and Group.

Here: `GroupVal` is the name of Group ComboBox and `QuotaVal` is the name of Category ComboBox.

I tried this code but it returns different errors every single time I fix one error.

```
Private Sub CreateAllKey_Click()

Dim QuotaList As String
Dim GroupList As String
Set QuotaList = Tables!Categories!Category
Set GroupList = Tables!Groups!Group
For Each QuotaList In QuotaVal
    For Each GroupList In GroupVal
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Merit List Generator", acViewNormal, acEdit
    Next
Next

MsgBox "All Lists Successfully Cleated", vbOKOnly, "Merit List Created!"

End Sub
```

And this following Code is returning only 1 value.. means, it runs on one value only and give out only 1 value;

```
    Dim QuotaList As Integer
    Dim GroupList As Integer

    For QuotaList = 0 To Me.QuotaVal.ListCount - 1
        If QuotaList = 0 Then
            Me.QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
        End If
        If QuotaList = 1 Then
            Me.QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
        End If
        If QuotaList = 2 Then
            Me.QuotaVal.Value = Null
        End If
        If QuotaList = 3 Then
            Me.QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
        End If
        If QuotaList = 4 Then
            Me.QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
        End If
        If QuotaList = 5 Then
            Me.QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
        End If
        For GroupList = 0 To Me.GroupVal.ListCount - 1
            If GroupList = 0 Then
                Me.GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
            End If
            If GroupList = 1 Then
                Me.GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
            End If
            If GroupList = 2 Then
                Me.GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
            End If
            If GroupList = 3 Then
                Me.GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
            End If
            If GroupList = 4 Then
                Me.GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
            End If
            If GroupList = 5 Then
                Me.GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
            End If
            DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

For example; I want something like this:

```
'Create lists of numbers and letters
Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 4, 7}
Dim letters() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}

'Iterate through the list by using nested loops.
For Each number As Integer In numbers
    For Each letter As String In letters
        Debug.Write(number.ToString & letter & " ")
    Next
Next
Debug.WriteLine("")
'Output: 1a 1b 1c 4a 4b 4c 7a 7b 7c
```

Consider the values of Numbers as Categories Table here and the value of Alphabets as Groups Table and run the 'Merit List Generator" Query each time it selects values instead of printing '1a, 1b, 1c, 4a, 4b,•••'

Keep in mind, all query formulas are correct and working.. they are working when I generate a single list when I input my own category and group values.

The errors I get after fixing one or the other error are: `'Can't Assign Value' 'Object Required' 'Data Mismatch'` Nothing worked!
If anyone has written such code, please send me... This is more complex than a tangled earphone. XD

Comment: You only set objects a string is not an object, remove the sets from ```Set QuotaList = Tables!Categories!Category``` and ```Set GroupList = Tables!Groups!Group```

Comment: Combo Boxes have a single value. There is nothing to iterate. My best guess is that you are using a continuous form where pairs of Categories and Groups are stored on a table. If that is what you are doing you have to read the values from the table, not from the form. If that is not what you are doing you have to revise your question. Beyond that your example code is very far from working. Almost every single line of code is wrong. I am guessing this is your first attempt at writing VBA probably writing code in any programming language. Mostly you are all over the place with variable types.

Comment: Please post the underlying SQL of *Merit List Generator* and advise if those are comboboxes or multi-select listboxes.

Comment: Whatever source you are using for example code, it is not VBA. Edit question to show sample source data and desired output.

Comment: I know Python, C++ and GW-BASIC but this is my first time making an Access database or using VBA. How do I read values from table? If my guess is not wrong, if I read values from a table, I will also have to add Docmd.OutputTo command to send output to the form? Because the merit list generator query takes values from the form, not the table. And I simply want to automate it, so that it automatically picks values from 2 combo boxxes where both contain 6 values of data, therefore; 36 combinations of merit list and 36 iterations performed by the nested loop.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you.. Do you want to see the query formulas? Or do you want me to write this code in SQL? I'm rather trying to avoid using SQL or Macro because I dont even have the slightest idea about them.

Comment: Output data from tables by building forms and reports bound to table or query. Have you studied an introductory Access tutorial? Impossible to avoid SQL. Access query builder generates SQL statements.

Comment: Apart from Query Formulae.. I dont wanna use SQL. Especially if I have to write my own.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can't really manage a db without using queries. SQL is language of queries. Building a query with Access query builder is easier than writing VBA.

Comment: I dont have any issues writing query formulae or using the builder or making queries.. I just need it to loop through the values of 2 tables or 2 combo boxes in the form and generate separate lists.

Comment: And where do you want those 'separate' lists to go? What I see from the example code is one list output to monitor. As already suggested, edit question to show source data and desired output. Show SQL statement of Merit List Generator.

Comment: Those lists will be used to create reports, when then will be printed. Umm, can I just simply upload my database here? I just signed up yesterday.

Comment: No, cannot upload files on this site. There are other sites where you can. If you want to produce Access reports, data must be in table(s). Reports use table or query as RecordSource.

Comment: wait.. lemme send you a drive link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16CSVpwEKJZwpfCtWsolAQmUyhA6Za0q-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to send the database to my senior for a review before it is implemented.. so, if you are free enough, please put the nested loop on 'Click' property after creating a 'CreateAll_Button' just below the 'Create_Button' in 'Generate List' Form. and send it to me through drive. I am successfully able to program all other codes and the query formulae, just this one is causing an issue. Or at least, write the body of the code in the answers written in between this; ``` 
Private Sub CreateAllKey_Click()

End Sub ```

Comment: Not going to download file. You haven't answered questions nor provided info as requested. Post sample data and desired output in question. Where should this data generated by 'loop' code go to? Presumably there is a table to populate.

Comment: I mentioned everything Bro.. Read it again. Including the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a Cartesian query. When a query lacks a JOIN clause, every record of each table will associate with every record of other table. The result is every possible combination of pairs.

`SELECT Category, Group FROM Categories, Groups;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: The example code you posted is taking two datasets and outputting every possible pairing. Query I describe does that.

Comment: Including the nested loop?

Comment: That is complete code. Build a query with Access query builder. Use query design grid or copy/paste into SQLView window.

Comment: That is not what I want to do.. 

Comment: Then you really need to better explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I dont have any issues writing query formulae or using the builder or making queries.. I just need it to loop through the values of 2 tables or 2 combo boxes in the form and generate separate lists.

Comment: Not working.. like i said, i am writing VBA, not SQL.