# IIF statement in Access Query is returning NULL in all values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am creating a Admission Management System as a Project of my College, it's the same database i about which i have having issues making a loop and automating it. Since i figured out the Looping in VBA, it is working..

Now, this issue involves between a field (OM/Quota) of a table (Candidates) and the formula of the query (Merit List Creator).
What i want is simply that it checked if the value of QuotaVal from the form is either Null (i.e; "") or "CIV" (Stands for Civilian) then it should update the Field, OM/Quota to "OM" else it should set OM/Quota to the value in the QuotaVal from the form.

What i tried;

```
        <Condition>      ,       <Value of OM/Quota if True>    ,    <value of OM/Quota if False>
```

`IIf([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]="","OM",IIf([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]="CIV","OM",[Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]))`

`IIf([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]=""or"CIV","OM",[Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])`

`Iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]=(""or"CIV"),[Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])`

`IIF([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] is Null OR [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] = "CIV", "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])`

`IIf(Nz([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal], "CIV") = "CIV", "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])`

None of them worked, they all returned Null (i.e; "") value to the field OM/Quota

Just to claify, want i need is;

> Iif value of QuotaVal = "Null" OR "CIV" then OM/Quota = "OM" else value of OM/Quota = QuotaVal

The output should be such that;

> The value of OM/Quota should be "OM" if QuotaVal = "CIV" OR "" Else value of OM/Quota = QuotaVal

Will i have to make a separate field for the Null formula in the query?

Which would be;

`iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] is Null, "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])`

Another question that popped up in my mind is;

Can i not use `iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] = Null or "CIV", "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])` instead?

The formula altogether should be;

`iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] is Null, "OM", iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] = "CIV","OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]))`

For Testing, i replaced the Loop with and ran all the above Formulas;

```
Private Sub CreateAllKey_Click()

    QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
    GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AR"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
    GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "AS"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "OM"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "OM"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "OM"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "OM"
    GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "OM"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "OM"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
    GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "DP"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "FGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-I"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-II"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Gen-Sci-III"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Humanities"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Engg"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")

    QuotaVal.Value = "RFGEI"
    GroupVal.Value = "Pre-Med"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Merit List Creator")



QuotaVal.Value = Null
GroupVal.Value = Null

MsgBox ("Merit Lists Created!")

End Sub
```

It still did not return values other than "OM" in the OM/Quota" Field when i ran the Query no matter what formula i tried given above. or in the solutions so far

**Pardon me if my English was difficult to understand, i am neither native nor do i have any other word to put them in**

Comment: An Empty string is not a NULL value. "" could just be removed data or an actual blank. NULL is unknown or missing Data. If the Column was NULL it would return the same for your Statement. Have you tried to evaluate with IsNull()?

Comment: yeah, in another formula, and it works..

Comment: can i not use "" OR "CIV" ??

Comment: Will i have to make a separate field in the query?

Comment: which would be; iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] is Null, "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])

Comment: my question is; can i not use iff([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] = Null or "CIV", "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]) instead?

Comment: You can. You just can't type the word "OR" and have the next Value. You need the Column/Field again like: `IIF([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] is Null OR [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] = "CIV", "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])`

Comment: Something might be wrong with the loop.. because it is only updating the values to 'OM' in the OM/Quota Field that have either Null in Quota or 'CIV"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237979/nested-loop-to-iterate-values-from-of-2-combo-boxes

Comment: Although, it's in VBa, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IIf(Nz([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal], "CIV") = "CIV", "OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal])
```

`Nz(expression, "CIV")` returns "CIV" in case the expression is Null.

So this expression returns `OM` in case `[Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]` is Null or `CIV`. Else it returns `[Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]`

Comment: I want to return "OM" regardless if QuotaVal is "CIV" or Null

Comment: Else, it should return the value of QuotaVal other than Null or "CIV"

Comment: Should do so, did you try?

Comment: if it's "CIV" or Null, it should return "OM"

Comment: i haven't tried that expression yet.. i tried mine; 
iif([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] is Null, "OM", iif([Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal] = "CIV","OM", [Forms]![Generate List]![QuotaVal]))

Comment: and it returned only the ones with Null or CIV Values

Comment: Something might be wrong with the loop.. because it is only updating the values to 'OM' in the OM/Quota Field that have either Null in Quota or 'CIV"

Comment: `if it's "CIV" or Null, it should return "OM"`: That's what it does, as you requested.

Comment: i also said that it should return the value of QuotaVal if it is other than Null or 'CIV'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237979/nested-loop-to-iterate-values-from-of-2-combo-boxes

Comment: `i also said that it should return the value of QuotaVal if it is other than Null or 'CIV'`: Correct. It also does this.

Comment: can you suggest a suitable loop?.

Comment: What loop? In your question is nothing about a loop. I just answered your question. Give it a try.

Comment: it's not giving other values like "AS" to "AS" or "AR" to "AR"

Comment: check teh loop in the other question of the link i sent you.

Comment: although, it's in VBa, not SQL.